# Efficient computation of marginalized multivariate normal likelihood

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, statistics, matrix-factorization

In general,if we know that the marginal Gaussian distribution for some variable $\textbf{x}$ and a conditional Gaussian distribution for some $\textbf{y}|\textbf{x}$ of the forms:
$$p(\textbf{x}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu},\Lambda^{-1})$$

$$p(\textbf{y}|\textbf{x}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{y}|A\textbf{x}+\textbf{b},L^{-1})$$
then the marginal distribution of $\textbf{y}$ and the conditional distribution of $\textbf{x}|\textbf{y}$ are given by:

$$ p(\textbf{y}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{y}|A\boldsymbol{\mu}+\textbf{b},L^{-1}+A\Lambda^{-1}A^{T})$$
$$p(\textbf{x}|\textbf{y}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{x}| \Sigma \left\{ A^{T} L ( \textbf{y} - \textbf{b} ) + \Lambda \boldsymbol{\mu} \right\} , \Sigma)$$

where :
$\Sigma = (\Lambda + A^{T}LA)^{-1}$

In my situation, I have a prior and likelihood: $$\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_p\sigma^2_\beta)$$
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} | \boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\beta},\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}).$$
Where $\hat{\textbf{S}}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\hat{\textbf{R}}$ is a symmetric correlation matrix. By making substitutions I arrive at the following marginalized likelihood :

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}|\sigma_\beta^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_\beta^2\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}^{-2}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}+\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}})$$

My question is this, if I want to find the value of $\sigma_\beta^2$ that maximizes the marginalized likelihood, do I have to recompute the cholesky of that entire covariance matrix from scratch every time I try out a new value of $\sigma_\beta^2$, or do I have other options?

If $\hat{\textbf{S}}=\text{diag}(1)$, then we can simply take  the eigenvalue decomposition of $\textbf{R}$:
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}|\sigma_\beta^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_\beta^2\textbf{R}^2+\textbf{R}) = \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_\beta^2\textbf{Q}\textbf{D}^2\textbf{Q}+\textbf{Q}\textbf{D}\textbf{Q}) \\ \rightarrow \textbf{Q}^T\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}|\sigma_\beta^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_\beta^2\textbf{D}^2+\textbf{D})$$
Where $\textbf{Q}$ are the eigenvectors of $\textbf{R}$ and $\textbf{D}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.  That's really easy to compute for different values of $\sigma_\beta^2$.  With $\hat{\textbf{S}}\neq\text{diag}(1)$ None of that works.  My intuition is that I'm trying to get a cheap full rank update of an eigenvalue decomposition, which is in general a no-go, but I would love to hear thoughts.

Comment: Could you clarify in linear algebra terms what it is you are trying to achieve? For example, do you want to solve linear systems of the form A + \sigma^2 B, for positive definite matrices A and B? That would be easy, so I guess that’s not it.